# save encoded String in hidden vs session

Tags: html, spring, session, jakarta-ee

**Given:**

I have a `List<ComplexObjectThatContainsOtherObjectsAndEvenLists>` and I want to retain this data across pages/requests. This objects is quite large containing up to 1000 objects.

**Current implementation:**

What I am currently doing is `serializing` this complex object using below (I just found this code here in SO and I am grateful to the author who unfortunately I cannot recall, I am sorry)

```
    public static String serialize(Object object) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteaOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        GZIPOutputStream gzipOut = null;
        try {
            gzipOut = new GZIPOutputStream(new Base64OutputStream(byteaOut));
            gzipOut.write(new Gson().toJson(object).getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (gzipOut != null) try { gzipOut.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
        }

        return new String(byteaOut.toByteArray());
    }
```

and hiding the `String` output `<input type="hidden">` in my page and passing at it back to my controller whenever I need it back. This string is around 1300-2000 characters in length.

**Question:**

Is saving this `String` in session better? (see below)

```
session.setAttribute("mySerializedString", mySerializedString);
```

Can you please provide pros and cons?

**My pros and cons so far (I am not sure though):**

I'm not sure but `hidden` implementation I think can have an effect while the page is rendered (since it's too long) and when it's submitted back to the controller, although this doesn't trouble me of manually unsetting the session variable if I choose the `session` implementation.

Comment: Why not just keeping it in the DB itself and carry around only its unique identifiers (usually in flavor of DB PK)?

Comment: Or, if it's supposed to present the result of something like a search query, just pass around the search query itself instead of copying half a DB into Java's memory and passing that around. With the search query you can just re-execute the query. Google also works that way and it's blazing fast. It even uses pagination so that you need to have only a subset of results at once (e.g. 10) in Java's memory.

Comment: It's a result from a complex join sir. It's not something I can paginate since everything from it is needed whenever it is to be used.

So basically sir, a re-query is "cheaper" (sorry for my lack of a better term) than carrying it around? (although the data technically  lives throughout 3-4 pages and is unset in the menu)